# Angular.js: Add tag every three elements

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a list of divs and I want to achieve the following html example:

```
<div class="groups">
  <div class="group">Whatever 1</div>
  <div class="group">Whatever 2</div>
  <div class="group">Whatever 3</div>
</div>
<div class="groups">
  <div class="group">Whatever 4</div>
  <div class="group">Whatever 5</div>
  <div class="group">Whatever 6</div>
</div>
```

I have the following:

```
<div class="group" ng_repeat="group in groups">
    <div>{{group.name}}</div>
</div>
```

How can I encapsulate "group" divs inside a "groups" for every three elements? Also I want to add elements dynamically and have the same behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: using a filter will not work do to infinite loop. Here is a solution with the filtering logic in the controller's watch function. It could be refactored and placed inside a service. But for the sake of simplicity it is not done here.

Here is a working Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/tINqbztypUqv674hvDbo

I would go with the solution proposed by @Mik378 augmented and manipulate data initially in your controller:

```
<div ng-controller="yourCtrl">

    <div class="groups" ng-repeat="groups in groupedArray">
        <div class="group" ng-repeat="group in groups">
            <div>{{group.name}}</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The controller:

```
angular.module('yourApp')
    .controller('yourCtrl', function ($scope) {
        $scope.tobeGroupedArray = [
            {name: 'group1'},
            {name: 'group2'},
            {name: 'group3'},
            {name: 'group4'},
            {name: 'group5'},
            {name: 'group6'},
            {name: 'group7'},
            {name: 'group8'},
            {name: 'group9'}
        ];

        $scope.$watch(
            'tobeGroupedArray',
            function (newVal) {
                if (!newVal) {
                    return;
                }
                $scope.groupedArray = [];
                newVal.forEach(function (group, idx) {
                    if (idx % 3 === 0) {
                        $scope.groupedArray.push([]);
                    }
                    $scope.groupedArray[$scope.groupedArray.length - 1].push(group);
                });
            },
            true
        );
    });
```

Comment: Yes this one works but it is a bit too specific for the groups, I was hoping for a more global answer but it is ok for now.

Comment: You can imagine doing much more. You can wrap that code inside a directive and choose how much items are grouped together etc. Let me know if I can help

Comment: I'll try to do it with directive but since I am still new to angular I would like to see it, if it isn't too much of a trouble :)

Comment: Your solution works for this specific simple thing, but if I have something else inside the div (for example an input field) it creates a really bad user experience because it unfocuses due to watch.

Comment: Please share more code to illustrate this behaviour.

Comment: I'll try to isolate it, I think it has to do with bindings but my page seems laggy when I add the above (well it isn't so simple example but I can't show all the example as it is a bit huge, I'll try to isolate and show it).

Comment: Crazy, it worked fine by just adding track by after the first ng-repeat. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I presume you would have an array of groups, and each "groups" being an array.
Why not the following:

```
<div class="groups" ng-repeat="groups in groupsArray">
  <div class="group" ng-repeat="group in groups">
      <div>{{group.name}}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have an array of group objects inside the groups. This one doesn't include three per groups tag.

Comment: Why not manipulating your groups in your controller initially?

Comment: Can you give me an example?

Comment: Can you give me the kind of specific groups you have initially? (the javascript object)

Comment: Please see my answer and its working plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/tINqbztypUqv674hvDbo